# Django signals not working with channels in multicontainer setup

Tags: python, django, docker, django-channels, daphne

I have django app and implementing websocket support with [channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [channels api](https://github.com/linuxlewis/channels-api). I am using demultiplexer with bindings to my models. For example when i save a model it will send the change to my open websocket connection.
Everything works OK if i run `./manage.py runserver 0:80` and have all in one container. **But if i separate my app to UWSGI, daphne and the worker containers using docker the signals are not triggered.** For example i want any celery worker (task) to trigger the signal and send update via the websocket. In my multicontainer setup the websocket connection is established OK and web works OK, but nothing triggers that signals.

How the signals are defined you can see here on [github](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/08ff57ac9b1d2599e071b62579c4ec64d1b08691/channels/binding/base.py#L83).

I am using django 1.9.12, python 2.7, docker and build on debian stretch.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  web:
    build: .
    ports: ["8001:80"]

  daphne:
    build: .
    command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 --access-log - -v 2 my_proj.asgi:channel_layer 

  ws_worker:
    build: .
    command: ./manage.py runworker -v 2

  celery_worker:
    build: .
    command: /usr/local/bin/celery -A my_proj worker
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream django {
    server unix:/home/docker/app.sock; 
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/docker/static/;
    }

    # proxy to other container
    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://daphne:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/docker/uwsgi_params;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the signals were not loading cause i defined binding classes else where than in models.py. If i load them after the models are loaded in **my_app/config.py** it works across multiple containers

```
from django.apps import AppConfig as DefaultAppConfig

class AppConfig(DefaultAppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        # for websockets bindigns
        from my_app.websockets.bindings_one import *
        from my_app.websockets.bindings_two import *
```